# json data in table through oracle apex web service

Tags: sql, json, oracle, web-services, oracle-apex

I have made a web service in oracle apex that returns a json data. I use it to create an application and display the data in form and report page. But i want the data to be displayed in tablular format.Need help in displaying it in tabular format.

***Preffered Output***

```
A   KEY
B   VALUE
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this need you can use 2 options

1 to use the builtin tools of apex which you can find examples by seraching "consuming web services in apex"
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/schema/50/Creating_RESTful_web_services/Creating_RESTful_web_services.html

2 you can use xmltable function in oracle sql with two sample codes as below

this codes shows the logic of json proccessing

```
select col1 d, col2 r
from xmltable (
        '/json/verumObjectList/row'
        passing apex_json.to_xmltype('

    {
  "verumModelObjectName": "Address",
  "verumObjectList": [
    {
      "locationID": "20005",
      "country": "ARE"
    },
    {
      "locationID": "31125",
      "country": "AUS"
    }],
  "statusCode": 200
}

')
        columns
           col1 number path '/row/locationID',
           col2 varchar2(5) path '/row/country' );
```

or
this code show to connect the remote server which has json service

```
           select  indexes ,types
from xmltable (
        '/json/hits/hits/row'
        passing apex_json.to_xmltype(APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST(
                    p_url               => 'YOUT_SERVICE_ADDRESS',
                    p_http_method       =>  'GET'))
        columns
           indexes varchar2(32) path '/row/_index',
           types varchar2(32) path '/row/_type',

);
```

Comment: for your specific data. it should be as below, for exact solution, you need check documentation and try at sql workshop .  select col1 A, col2 KEY
from xmltable (
        '/json'
        passing apex_json.to_xmltype('

    {
      "A": "B",
      "KEY": "Value"
    }


')
        columns
           col1 varchar2(1) path '/row/A',
           col2 varchar2(5) path '/row/KEY' );